# Json: parse to display in HTML using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

I'm trying to parse data from a page of JSON in my ASP.NET MVC 1.0 web application.  I need this data to display in a table on page load and I'm having a great deal of trouble mainly because I've never used JSON before.  The JQuery site gives pretty terrible examples as well.  This is what I have so far, I need help writing a function:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:1909/encoders",
            function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function() {

                });
            });
    });
```

The URL above is currently just displaying JSON and the two columns I am getting from the SQL server to produce the JSON are EncoderName and EncoderStatus.  The  id is displayencoders.

Thanks!

edit:
my controller looks like this:

```
[UrlRoute(Name = "GetEncoders", Path = "encoders")]
        public ActionResult GetEncoders() {
            var encoders = Database.GetEncoders();

            return Json(encoders);
        }
```

when compiled my /encoders/ looks like:

```
{

    * EncoderName: "rmcp2-encoder"
    * EncoderStatus: "inactive"

}
```

Comment: What's the server-side code look like?

Comment: Also, what does your JSON look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:1909/encoders", function(data) {

        $("#div-my-table").text("<table>");

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $("#div-my-table").append("<tr><td>" + item.EncoderName +"</td><td>" + item.EncoderStatus + "</td></tr>");
        });

        $("#div-my-table").append("</table>");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

funnily enough, i use an almost similar methodology but instead of parsing the json, i actually apply the html formatting to the json structure from a helper method in my controller. so basically, my controller passes back a json result fully formatted and all the jquery function has to do is place it inside the relevant div which in this case is $('#propertyList').html(data).

here's kinda how it looks on the view:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetLocationHighlites() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $.getJSON('/en/Property/GetLocationHighlites/', null,
            function(data) { JsonData(data); });
    }

    function JsonData(data) {
        if (data.length != 0) {
            $('#propertyList').html(data);
            $('#propertyList').slideDown('fast');
            return false;
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        GetLocationHighlites();
    });
</script>
```

and in the controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetLocationHighlites()
    {
        IBlockData block = WebPagesMapper.GetLocationHighlites(propertiesWorldwideLuxury);
        string htmlBlock = string.Format(_block, block.Header, block.Content);
        return Json(htmlBlock);
    }
```

_block in the above JsonResult GetLocationHighlites() is a string constant along the lines of:

```
private string _block = @"<div class='Block'>
                       <div class='header'>
                        {0}
                       </div>
                       <div class='BlockContent-body'>
                        {1} 
                       </div>
                     </div>";
```

my take on the subject, and in this case, my (feeble :)) attempt to keep it DRY.

Answer (score 1):

of course, you could ALSO/ALTERNATIVELY return a string (rather than a Json result). I actually got to thinking with the answer above and realised that this was perhaps the 'best case' for my purposes. so i now have (in view):

```
$.get('/en/Property/GetLocationHighlites/'
```

rather than:

```
$.getJSON('/en/Property/GetLocationHighlites/'
```

and have amended the controller function to:

```
public string GetLocationHighlites()
{
    IBlockData block = WebPagesMapper.GetLocationHighlites(propertiesWorldwideLuxury);
    string htmlBlock = string.Format(_block, block.Header, block.Content);
    return htmlBlock;
}
```

hope this doesn't muddy the waters...